# How to loop through complex nested objects and double Arrays Angular 10

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I have  class A and i want to print out the amount of tables that the interface B has in its array of People. I also want to print out the amount of rows to each table that interface People has in its array of Person.

I mean i want to print i out the tables in the xxxxxxxx.html page

how can i do this ?

Data structure

```
export export class A {
readonly data: B;}
   
export interface B {
readonly data: Array<Array<People>>;}

export interface People {
readonly header: string;
readonly key: string;
readonly data: Array<Person>;}

export interface Person {
readonly name: string;
readonly age: string;}
```

Comment: could you be more specific? there are multiple ways to print lists of Items. lists, nested lists, tables...

Comment: ok  lets say  interface B has 3 People in Array<People>, then i want to print 3 tables in the .html page.  The Array that wraps  the people has only 1 Array.  then for every table i want to print the amount of rows that interface People has in its Array of Person

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 nested \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272911/angular2-nested-ngfor)

Comment: no thats a different problem

Comment: something like this :                                                                                                
                                                                                           
    `code  <table *ngFor=" let t of a.b.data; let i = index">                                           
 <thead> 
 <th>Name</th> 
  <th>Age</th> 
 </thead> 
 <tr *ngFor="let rows of t.data; let i = index"> 
 <td>{{rows.name}}</td> 
 <td>{{rows.name}}</td> 
</tr> 
 </table>`

Comment: I solved  here is the code

Comment: `<div *ngFor=" let dat of a.b.data; let i = index"><table *ngFor=" let ta of dat; let i index"><thead><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></thead><tr *ngFor="let row of ta.data; let i = index"><td>{{row.name}}</td><td>{{row.age}}</td></tr></table></div>`